# What is the purpose of the Legacy Artifact?

Tags: darksiders-2

Vulgrim sells an item called the Legacy Artifact, worth 25000 Gilt.  I purchased it, only to find that it is a level 40 (effectively unusable) talisman with no effects.  Am I missing something?

*Note:* This item is only available with the Argul's Tomb DLC pack installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The talisman is meant to act as a filler for sacrificing to a possessed weapon (but see the last paragraph for an alternative use).

If you are sacrificing various items to a possessed weapon, only four of the attributes from the sacrificed items will be provided as choices to add onto the weapon when it levels up.  More desirable attributes, such as Health on Crit, have lower priority than attributes like Defense or Arcane, and therefore may not appear as choices when you've sacrificed other equipment in order to level up the weapon.

By providing no effects of any kind, and through its high level, this talisman can be used to force the possessed weapon to level up without inserting any additional attributes.  This means that you can sacrifice an item with a specific desired effect, then sacrifice this talisman to ensure that you can add the attribute you actually want to add.  Note that you may need more than one such talisman for high-level weapons to level up.

---

If the Legacy Artifact is sacrificed to a possessed weapon without sacrificing anything else since the last level-up, two random attributes will appear for selection.  These attributes may include those that are not transferable from other items (excluding Experience, Gilt Found, and special abilities), such as Health/Wrath/Reaper Energy on Execute and Reaper Energy on Crit/Per Kill/Regen.  This is the only way to insert these attributes into a possessed weapon.  (Credit: [Darksiders Dungeon Wiki](http://darksidersdungeon.net/wiki/Legacy_Artifact); some parts are from my own testing)